# Racing game side walls

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am currently designing a track in blender for a racing game in Unity. 
My question concerns the side walls:
If you look at current formula e games like Real Racing, there are commercials all along the side walls (e.g. DHL, Visa, ...). I also want to randomly distribute different commercials along the racing track.

Are there any common/best practices for doing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to about materials for Unity

Comment: You [can't export materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures). I'd advise using some sort of modules or reusable repeating parts, unwrap your meshes properly in Blender then build your random-textured materials in Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hardly recommend, that distributing textures randomly on a Mesh, is a task you would perform in Unity.

Theoretically it is possible to distribute textures randomly on a Material. But if you don't bake them to a simple UV-layout, I am afraid, you wont be able to ship this material to Unity.

But I would ask this question on a Unity focused platform.

EDIT:

But if you want to do something like this in Blender, I think this is only possible with the help of Python scripting or an osl shader.

Even if this Question will be closed, I have to share the result of my tests, because if not, I would have wastet to much of my time.

The closest result **wich I found** was to procect multible textures onto the mesh like decals. Therefore you have to use external objects as texture Coordinates.

The results can only be seen in the render mode.

[image: Multible Textures projetet via empties]

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. 
Staying in Blender, how would I do this?

Comment: I edited my Answer